# React : meaning of state written like ...state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new on React, could you say me what's the meaning of this?

```
const new_venues = this.state.venues.map((venue) =>
 place_id === venue.place_id ? { ...venue, open : !venue.open } : { ...venue, open: false });
```

I know the syntax cond ? cond_true : cond:false, but I don't know the meaning of  `...venue`

Comment: Basic JS questions are best served by learning JS. Any recent JS tutorial will  cover information like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `spread syntax`. See [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

It is a shorthand method for adding all the properties of the specified object (in your case `venue`) to a new object. Prior to this, the equivalent was to use `Object.assign()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

```
const newObject = Object.assign({}, venue);
```